# Grep : I/O , exclude

Tags: ubuntu, grep

How I can 1- crawl through all sub folders and save their names to txt file using `grep` (or any other useful alternative)
2- and then use this .txt listto exclude listed files for another 'grep' command

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and its `-prune` option to skip a path:

```
find . -path './path-to-skip/*' -prune -o -type f -exec grep 'PATTERN' {} +
```

Comment: I don't want to skip a patch

Comment: I just need to skip files with specific name

Comment: @I'mDoneOK: So use `-name` instead of `-path` or whatever you find appropriate in `man find`.